# Unable to make "IDataStatistics:UniqueValues" work in .Net

Tags: arcobjects, add-in

I would like to use IDataStatistics:UniqueValues to iterate through a set of unique values.  This worked flawlessly in VB6 and VBA but I am having a difficult time making it work in VS 2013, ArcGIS 10.3, targeting .Net 3.5.

I am following the example shown [**here**](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/arcobjects/esriGeoDatabase/DataStatistics_Example.htm)

[Debugging InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code error from ArcObjects DataStat?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10030/arcobjects-datastat-error) is a similar post with no resolution. I've already tried the suggestions provided there to no avail.

The error I get always occurs on the  **pEnumVar = CType(pData.UniqueValues, IEnumVariantSimple)** line with Err.Description: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.CustomMarshalers.EnumeratorViewOfEnumVariant' to type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IEnumVariantSimple'."

I would really like to make this work rather than having to nest my loop to get the unique values the long way...

Here my code:

```vb
'pField As IField, pSelectionSet As ISelectionSet2 passed in 

Dim pData As IDataStatistics = New DataStatistics 
Dim pStatResults As IStatisticsResults
Dim pEnumVar As IEnumVariantSimple 
Dim value As Object

... ...

pSelectionSet.Search(Nothing, False, pCursor) 
pData = New DataStatistics
pData.Field = pField.Name 
pData.Cursor = pCursor
EnumVar = CType(pData.UniqueValues, IEnumVariantSimple) 
value = pEnumVar.Next
    Do Until IsDBNull(value)    ...     ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [IDataStatistics.UniqueValues](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IDataStatistics_UniqueValues.htm) returns a [System.Collections.IEnumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx)

Frankly, I've found it easier to just use a search cursor and populate a [Generic Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) than to deal with IDataStatistics.

Comment: I know this question relates to 10.3 but its worth mentioning that there was a bug introduced by ESRI in a service pack for 10.1 which broke this interface and I too ended up just using cursors and have stuck with them, although I think ESRI should have resolved the issue by now.

Answer (score 2):

I was incorrect in saying that no suggestion in [THIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10030/arcobjects-datastat-error) post worked. Over the last decade I learned to always seriously consider anything mr. @Kirk Kuykendall posts with extra attention. The credit for this answer should go to him but since the OP didn't mark the original question as answered I will do it here and if Kirk can just copy his comment here and make it an answer I will mark his as the correct answer.

Turns out the problem is not with IDataStatistics but with the IEnumVariantSimple enumerator. I was able to confirm that although IDataStatistics:UniqueValues should return an IEnumVariantSimple type enumerator I was under certain situations able to crash it with a "this Type is not supported" error. Kirk stated "Looks like IDataStatistics.UniqueValues returns a System.Collections.IEnumerator" (NOT IEnumVariantSimple)  Once I changed the enumerator type I was able to make it work. This system enumerator works differently but it is perfectly usable:

```
    Dim pData As IDataStatistics = New DataStatistics
    Dim pStatResults As IStatisticsResults
    Dim pEnumVar As IEnumVariantSimple
    Dim pEnum As System.Collections.IEnumerator
    Dim value As Object

    ...
    ...

    pSelectionSet.Search(Nothing, False, pCursor)
    pData = New DataStatistics
    pData.Field = pField.Name
    pData.Cursor = pCursor
    pEnum = CType(pData.UniqueValues, System.Collections.IEnumerator)
    pEnum.Reset()
    pEnum.MoveNext()
    value = pEnum.Current

    Do Until value Is Nothing
        ...
        ...
```